# Nextjs Image an issue with "loader" property that does not implement width

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

This is my code for the Nextjs Image component:

```
...  Cell: ({ value }: CellType) => (
  <Image
    priority
    src={value}
    loader={() => value}
    className={''}
    height={100}
    width={100}
    alt={'profile_picture'}
  />
),
```

[image]

Does it mean I need a custom loader function to get rid off the warning? Thanks!

Comment: If you're not applying any optimisations through a 3rd party cloud provider (your `loader` isn't doing anything), you might as well just use `unoptimized={true}` on the `Image`.

Comment: @juliomalves that actually makes sense. Thank you! I'll update my Q!

Answer (score 9):

I had a same issue like yours and solved by adding `unoptimized={true}` prop into the `<Image>` tag.
If you don't apply optimizations, you need to announce that you don't optimize. 
Something like below:

```
<Image
    priority
    src={value}
    loader={() => value}
    unoptimized={true}  // <=== insert this prop
    className={''}
    height={100}
    width={100}
    alt={'profile_picture'}
  />
```

Please let me know if it work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error but what I have done to fix it is to incorporate in the `next.config.js` file the `URL` of my media files, in my case it is **cloudinary**, the file should look like this:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  images: {
    domains: [
      'res.cloudinary.com'
    ],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

And when I use the image component (next/image) I remove the loader and just put the URL like this:

```js
<Image
  key={element.id}
  src={element.url}
  width={500}
  height={500}
  alt="some description"
/>
```

I don't use `unoptimized={true}` because the point is that the component changes the quality of the image according to the client's device.

**good look :)**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this:

Added this definition to loader attribute-:

**loader={({ src, width }) => { return src + "?w=" + width }}**

```
<Image
    priority
    src={value}
    loader={({ src, width }) => { return src + "?w=" + width }}
    height={100}
    width={100}
    alt={'profile_picture'}
/>
```